# Default namespace is not evaluated when stating lein repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, cider

I have troubles getting my default namespace invoked when I start lein repl :headless from emacs cider.

My project.clj has :repl entry defined:

```
  :repl-options { :init-ns dev.core }
```

When I cider-jack-in from project.clj file, I indeed end up in dev.core ns:

```
  dev.core> *ns*
  #<Namespace dev.core>
```

However, when I look interns, I get:

```
  dev.core> (ns-interns *ns*)
  {}
```

When I reload namespace:

```
  dev.core> (use 'dev.core :reload)
  nil
  dev.core> (ns-interns *ns*)
  {start-cljs-repl #'dev.core/start-cljs-repl, stop-server #'dev.core/stop-server}
```

My namespace gets loaded.
It seems that internally leiningen uses (require ...) method to load namespace, but can't find any info in docs about this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After setting the initial namespace, use `:init` to load the symbols.

```
:repl-options {:init-ns dev.core
               :init (use 'dev.core :reload)}
```